Enabling vSAN on existing cluster in vCenter
I currently have 3 clusters in vCenter, all with their own ESXi hosts and VM's running on those resources. I want to enable and utilize vSAN within 1 cluster for now and then expand it throughout the entire datacenter.
Here's my question:
The cluster I intend to enable vSAN on has VM's and data stored on those disks within that cluster already. If I enable vSAN on those hosts within that cluster will it erase or corrupt the data currently on those disks within that cluster?
If so, can I migrate the VM's to different hosts and enable vSAN 1 host a time and until my goal is achieved without messing up and of the running VM's or data on those disks?
Thank you.

Do you have enough storage to have the vSAN point to a blank datastore, and do storage livemotion to that storage ?

Yes I've already migrated my active VM's to another cluster but after reading up on it some more it looks like vSAN won't see datastores that already have a RAID configuration or have been claimed by an existing host. So I'm guessing I'll have to go back into every single host and reconfigure their attached disks and bring them in as individual JBOD's.

Yes, your are right HW RAID controller should be in HBA mode to be supported by vSAN. https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.vsan-planning.doc/GUID-4B738A10-4506-4D70-8339-28D8C8331A15.html
vSAN itself can be configured on an existing cluster.
If you want to utilize existing hardware RAID to create redundant shared storage, StarWind VSAN can be used. https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san
